# Emulator (AVD) is not starting in android studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Android launch emulator is not starting.

I have used the configurations as showed in images and its is displaying just black window with text android in it.

Config Images:
AVD configuration:

[image]

Emulator:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your console log?

Comment: Console just showing below information (Waited for more than 1 hour):                  

Waiting for device.
Target device: Sudhakar_Demo_2_API_23 [emulator-5554]

Uploading file

local path: D:\<My Project location> -Demo\app\biuld\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.revu.revu

Comment: I have changed the RAM size to 512 MB. Then it works file. But I dont know how it makes the difference. Would be helpful if you explain me why?

Comment: Your apk needed more RAM than you had previously allocated.